# TypeScript - Create an interface for complicated objects

Tags: angular, typescript, interface

The following variable contains a list of objects:

```
scenes = {
    sky: {
      image: 'assets/1.jpg',
      points: {
        blue_area: {
          x: 1,
          y: 2
        },
      }
    },
    blue_area: {
      image: 'assets/2.jpg',
      points: {
        sky: {
          x: 1,
          y: 2
        }
      }
    }
};
```

How I can declare an interface for this kind of variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare the type of Scenes as:

```
type Points = {
  [key: string]: {
    x: number;
    y: number;
  }
}

type Scenes = {
  [key: string]: {
    image: string;
    points: Points;
  }
}

let scenes: Scenes = {
    sky: {
      image: 'assets/1.jpg',
      points: {
        blue_area: {
          x: 1,
          y: 2
        },
      }
    },
    blue_area: {
      image: 'assets/2.jpg',
      points: {
        sky: {
          x: 1,
          y: 2
        }
      }
    }
};
```

Comment: `sky` and `blue_area` are names that can be replaced by any other, my intention was to make something general which compactible to any other names.

Comment: Well, in that case, you can just replace `[key in ScenceNames]?` with `[key: string]`.